# Calling super() with no Superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, super, superclass

What happens (if anything) when a constructor calls 'super()' without having any superclass besides Object? Like so:

```
public class foo implements Serializable, Comparable {

  int[] startPoint;

  public foo() {

    super();

    startPoint = {5,9};
  }
}
```

Edit:

###### So if this does nothing, why would anyone explicitly write that in code? Would it make any difference if I just delete that line?

Comment: Read all about it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html

Comment: Seen all answers, no one really clearly is answering this question which is "Why would anyone explicitly write that in code"  Everybody simply are pointing to the fact that, is needed when you call from a sub-class that inherits from a super class (dah.. this is the same in many programming language, nothing new and is not what the question is about) or that having super(); with no super class is useless. Good to know but still, why would someone do this? I saw it in some code?  Bad practice ? Reduntant code? some obscure old fashioned java-comunity-rule?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is always OK to delete the line `super();` from any constructor, and there is nothing particular about the constructors of classes that extend `Object`. The call of the nullary superclass constructor is always implied, so whether you write it down or not, you always get the exact same semantics.

Note that this means that if you omit a call to the superclass constructor that does something big, like start database connections or the whole GUI, all this will happen whether or not you actually write `super();`.

Comment: Sure, but then why does anyone ever write it? Why does it even exist as a keyword?

Comment: @fakefake.. You would need to write it if you want to invoke parameterized constructor of super class. Compiler by default adds only a call to `0-arg constructor`.

Comment: @fakefake No particular reason except "clarity". Java has lots of features and even "best practices" geared towards absolute beginners. When I see that line in any code I ever edit, I promptly delete it. But if you question the existence of the very concept of superclass constructor call, that is a completely different thing. Of course those calls are very much needed (as already explained above by Rohit).

Answer (score 8):

`super()` is the first call in constructor either it is done explicitly or implicitly.
(But of course you might need to change parameters to match parent's constructor.)

Your code:

```
public foo() 
{
    startPoint = {5,9};
}
```

What compiler sees from the code above:

```
public foo()
 {
    super();
    startPoint = {5,9};
 }
```

So `super()` is invoked whether you put it explicitly in your code or not.
Since all classes derive from `Object` class, you are calling constructor of Object with your `super()` call because your class doesn't have any intermediate parents.

Comment: Well, this answer really gives a valuable information for beginners, but I'm afraid it isn't really answering the question currently. Please update it.

Comment: @RohitJain can you explain what is missing dear Rohit?

Comment: @ivanovic.. Actually, OP is asking, where is the super() call delegated if there is not super class (explicit) for a class. But still I would give you a +1 for this answer. :)

Comment: @RohitJain There's never a class without a super-class, literally never. *All* classes inherit from `Object` (except primitives and arrays, of course, to which this question doesn't apply). The only thing that he may be missing is noting that regardless of whether or not you specify it, it doesn't change the order in which things happen.

Comment: @ivanovic. Yeah it's perfect now. Cheers :)

Comment: How did this discussion end up in agreement on the falsehood that arrays are not Objects? **Every array in Java is a subclass of `Object`**.

Answer (score 7):

There is always a super class called `Object`, so it will invoke constructor of `Object`

Answer (score 2):

That just calls the `Object()` constructor, just as if you had any other superclass with a constructor that has no parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, there is a super class (Object).

The default object constructor will be called.

Answer (score 1):

It calls Object's constructor, which is empty (does nothing).

Answer (score 1):

super() always call to the constructor to Object class if the class doesn't extends from one class.

> Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a super class. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

[Check this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)